# Efficient way to create a Ruby hash from multiple ActiveRecord queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to solve an issue in an elegant way.

I have a class:

```
class Pages < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Relations
  has_many :contents
  has_many :videos
  has_many :galleries
  has_many :surveys
  has_many :documents

end
```

I want to create a hash like this

```
{"videos"=>{:resource_type=>"Video", :resource_id=>2, :resource_name=>"Video di prova"}, "documents"=>{}, "contents"=>{}, "surveys"=>{}, "galleries"=>{}}
```

collecting the records in my associations.

I wrote a method

```
def get_page_resources
    result = {}
    ['videos','galleries','documents','surveys','contents'].each do |r|
      if self.try(r)
        res_collection = {}
        self.send(r).each do |resource|
          res_collection.merge!(resource_type: resource.class.name)
          res_collection.merge!(resource_id: resource.id)
          res_collection.merge!(resource_name: resource.name)
        end
        result[r] = res_collection
      end
    end
    return result
  end
```

It works but I think it is quite ugly.
Is there a better way to write this method?

Comment: In your sample output, I believe you meant for each of the members of the outer hash to be an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would refactor your code to the following, which I think is fairly readable:

```
def resources
  %w(videos galleries documents surveys contents).map do |name|
    [
      name, send(name).map do |resource|
        {
          resource_type: resource.class.name,
          resource_id: resource.id,
          resource_name: resource.name
        }
      end
    ]
  end.to_h
end
```

- Beginning a method with `get_` is not idiomatic Ruby. Just name the method after what it returns. "page" doesn't need to be in the name, either, since this is a method on `Pages`. (By the way, it's more usual for an ActiveRecord model to be named in the singular rather than plural.)
- `%w()` is a little nicer than a regular array of quoted words.
- `r` is not a reader-friendly variable name. I used `name`, meaning "resource name", since it's obvious from context that it's the name of a resource.
- The pattern of creating an enumerable, building it by iterating over another enumerable, and then returning it, can usually be made clearer and shorter with `map` or `each_with_object`.
- When converting an array to a hash, it is often convenient to `map` it to an array of `[key, value]` pairs and then convert it to a hash with `.to_h`.
- `try(r)` doesn't do anything, since the association methods always return a true value. I removed it.
- `self.` is not necessary when calling a method other than an assignment method.
- The `merge!`s can just be replaced with a hash literal.
- `return` is unnecessary at the end of a method, and not idiomatic.

Refactoring is fun, so I answered your question as stated, but I agree with Nermin that it looks like you might want to look in to a serialization framework.

Comment: resource is a collection, not an object. resource.id return nil. I must also iterate inside the resource...

Answer (score 1):

You could clean it up by extracting the res_collection thing into a method like this:

```
def get_page_resources
  {
    videos:    res_collection(:videos),
    galleries: res_collection(:galleries),
    documents: res_collection(:documents),
    surveys:   res_collection(:surveys),
    contents:  res_collection(:contents)
  }
end

private

# this probably doesn't do what it was supposed to, but 
# just to give an impression without digging further into your
# code..
def resource_collection(resource)
  res_collection = {}
  self.send(resource).each do |resource|
    res_collection.merge!(resource_type: resource.class.name)
    res_collection.merge!(resource_id: resource.id)
    res_collection.merge!(resource_name: resource.name)
  end
  res_collection
end
```